# SF novel using "sun side" and "dark(?) side" for "pro" & "con"

Tags: story-identification, novel

I'm looking for a novel I first read some time ago, probably 1990s or 2000s, and at least once since. I read it in the US as a used paperback in English, and as far as I know that's the original language. I don't remember anything else about the physical book.

Setting is a distant or alien culture. I don't remember the plot at all.

The key detail I'm sure about is that a character (young-adult female? fighter? human?) lists pros & cons of some action using the terminology "sun side" and "dark side" (I think; maybe "night side"). This phrasing is, I think, unique to that character, not pervasive.

Trying to match the "feel" of the story to books & authors I have re-read many times, I came up with Sherri Tepper (Revenants?), Sarah Zettel (Quiet Invasion?), and Nancy Kress (An Alien Light?) but I couldn't nail it down. Scarlett in the Aurora Rising trilogy hits some of the same notes, with her tersely-worded journal entries listing pros & cons of her exes, but it's definitely not that.

Searches that included "sunside" or "sun side" turned up lots of tales using the terms literally (e.g. the day side of Mercury), but even after filtering those out I saw nothing like the metaphorical use I'm seeking.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found it! It **was** Nancy Kress's "An Alien Light" (1988), but not a character I had thought of. The Library-Mind of the Ged (alien race) uses this phrasing. The first example is at the beginning of Chapter 8, where the Ged discuss the two subgroups of humans entering their city R'Frow:

> Another contradiction ...
>
> Sunside: Most cooperation was shown by the subgroup 'Jelite'...
> Unlike the other subgroup, they entered R'Frow with order and peace ...
>
> Darkside: In both speech and actions of the humans outside R'Frow,
> the subgroup 'Jelite' had the highest content of violence.

Answer (score 5):

Could be [**Jack of Shadows**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jack_of_Shadows) by Roger Zelazny. It is about a planet with constant night on one side (where magic rules) and a day on the other (science side).

> The novel is set in a world that is tidally locked. Thus one side of
> the planet is always in light, and the other in darkness. Science
> rules on the dayside, while magic holds sway in the night.
>
> Powerful magical entities live on the night side of the planet, and
> for the most part the entities' magical powers emanate from distinct
> loci. Jack of Shadows (also known as Shadowjack), the main character,
> is unique among the magical beings in that he draws his power not from
> a physical location but from shadow itself. He is nearly incapacitated
> in complete light or complete darkness, but given access to even a
> small area of shadow, his potency is unmatched.
>
> Jack's only friend, the creature Morningstar, is punished by being
> trapped in stone at the edge of the night, to be released when dawn
> comes. His torso and head protrude from the rock, and he awaits the
> sun that will never rise.
>
> Jack seeks "The Key That Was Lost", Kolwynia. The Key itself and the
> consequences of its use parallel Jack's progress in his own endeavors.
> Ultimately, the Key will be responsible for Jack's salvation and his
> doom.
>
> Fleeing the dark side, Jack gets access to a computer and uses it to
> recover Kolwynia. This makes him unbeatable, but not all-powerful.
> Having made a mess of ruling with his new powers, he seeks the advice
> of Morningstar, who advises him to destroy The Machine at the Heart of
> the World, which maintains the world's stability, and set it rotating.

Comment: That sounds like a literal use of "dayside" and "dark side". Do the characters use the terms metaphorically too? Also, what I'm remembering is definitely *sun* side not day side.

Comment: @DrAsheRGBA IIRC it was "day side" and "daysiders". It was physical "presence of the day", not metaphorical.